# Detect how long it takes for a file to upload (PHP)

Tags: php, upload

Is it possible to know (serverside) the time it took for a file to upload? I have an image upload API and in my response I'd like to return the upload time (not including script execution time).

Comment: show us the code youre using to upload the file

Comment: a file is uploaded by posting it to my api url as multipart/form-data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think yes, there is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` variable that indicates the start of HTTP request, so on the very beginning of your script:

```
$upload_time = time() - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

Result will be in seconds.

Comment: Sad to hear that, but please note that it is problem with your server configuration, not the answer.

Comment: As you said, did turn out to be a bad server configuration. However, I got some useful answers too. The Apache header solution on the other question actually allows for the use of microtime, which is of a finer granularity than `REQUEST_TIME`. I'm going to request the two questions be merged.

Comment: At the moment yes, but from php 5.4 onward `REQUEST_TIME` will also contain microseconds, so it should be independent from web server.

Answer (score 6):

Seems this method works pretty OK actually:

1. Send off an ajax request (right before form posts) to the server which stores a session timestamp
2. Post the form
3. Check difference in the receiving end :)

---

#### HTML

```
<?php session_start(); // must be at the top ?>

<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#upload-form').submit(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'start-timer.php',
                type: 'POST',
                context: this,
                success: function() { this.submit(); },
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### start-timer.php

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['time'] = microtime(true);
```

#### upload.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

if( ! isset($_FILES['file'])
||  ! isset($_SESSION['time'])
||  $_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK
||  ! is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
    exit('stuff went wrong...');
}

$time = microtime(true) - $_SESSION['time'];
unset($_SESSION['time']);
echo round($time, 3).'s';
```

Working sample: http://samples.geekality.net/upload-timer

Comment: Looks promising. I'll see if I can make it work, and edit your answer when I do.

Comment: @GustavBertram Got curious, so tested it out at home, and got it working. Updated the answer and created a working sample as well :)

Comment: Hi. I actually got it working myself, and I did submit an update to your answer, but I guess your update overwrote that. :) Your answer works very nicely, but the bigger surprise is that I got the Apache header answer working.

Comment: @Svish I took your code but didn't get it working, always get a "stuff went wrong...", no matter what file I upload.I realised, that in your code above was missing a ```action="upload.php"```, but even with it, no success on different servers. I would be grateful if you could check your code once more, maybe you find the reason (Unfortunately, I am not savvy enough in PHP programming).

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't measure anything inside the receiving script.
Just because it is started right after the upload (handled by the web-server) ends.

So, as Svish said, the AJAX call and timestamp in the session would be easiest solution.

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife has proven this wrong. His Apache header solution is pure PHP, and it actually works.

Comment: You either don't understand this solution or didn't read my answer. **Nothing** wrong in it. "Apache header" solution clearly says that measurement is done by the **Apache webserver**, NOT php script. But the receiving script itself CANNOT measure anything, for the reason I wrote. It can only get the result done by someone else. Not to mention that Apache header is NOT "pure PHP solution" but session approach **IS indeed pure php** as it involves nothing else. NOTHING in my answer contradicts with accepted answer. May be you need better understanding of how PHP works. Don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Then what about this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931959/detect-how-long-it-takes-for-a-file-to-upload-php It does not even require changes to Apache. You are only correct in a very technical and limited sense. While the measurement cannot start and end inside the PHP script, there are at least three ways to measure the time it takes to upload a file to a PHP script. Your answer may be technically correct, but it is not useful.

Comment: My answer has 2 points. 1. It correcting your wrong assumption that anything can be measured inside of receiving script - a very important point of understanding the underlaying mechanisms. 2. It has an outline of practical solution which you confirmed as a working one. If I were you, I wouldn't call it useless. It seems it's something personal.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the link.

http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/01/02/measuring-apache-request-processing-time/

It shows how to configure apache to log time time the request is receieved by apache.

Then you can use the apache_request_headers fundtion in PHP and extract out that time.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Maybe this way, you can figure out the time between when apache starts recieving the file, and when it passes processing to php?

Might need to do some testing, as I have not tried this. Let me know if it works... :)

**UPDATE BY [@GustavBertram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005039/gustav-bertram):**

Note: I edited the answer instead of my own question, since I want to document the attempt separately for each answer.

I enabled mod_headers in Apache, and added the following config file:

```
#/etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.conf
RequestHeader set X-Request-Received: %t
```

I then updated my script:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Upload:<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php

// Get the request headers
$REQUEST_HEADERS = apache_request_headers();

// Extract $t value from header
parse_str($REQUEST_HEADERS['X-Request-Received']);

// Massage string to get float in seconds
$received_time = substr_replace($t, '.', 10, 0);

// Get the current microtime as float in seconds
$current_time = microtime(1);

$upload_time = $current_time - $received_time;

echo $received_time . " \n <BR />";
echo $current_time . " \n <BR />";

echo $upload_time;
```

I tested it both on my local machine, and on a remote machine in the network, with a 700MB file.

Comment: I managed to get this answer working after updating the php.ini values as indicated in the question. This is actually a very nice solution, especially since it only uses PHP.

Answer (score 0):

At Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.2.17, I use apache_response_headers() lead with flush() command, another way it does not work, i receive header with one variable. ob_end_flush() did not help me.
REQUEST_TIME variable of $_SSERVER is elegant equivalent but pay attention this works from PHP 5.1.

Answer (score -2):

I have a simple logic in mind

when image is posted for upload

save starting time in a variable and set another variable for e.g. uploadStatus =0, then when upload is done set the variable to uploadStatus = 1  and also save the end time in another variable.

On upload check if uploadStatus == 1, then subtract the starting time from end time and you will get the upload time.

Comment: Then please, modify my example script to show your solution, and put it in your answer.